# Service Fabric Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage powershell crash

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After upgrade to sdk 2.5.216 and runtime 5.5.216 Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage command works only for complete package. In case of partial app upgrade (some Pkg are removed) it results in "**Windows PowerShell has stopped working**". I have tested on several computers and several apps. to reproduce:

1. create test app with 2 services and deploy.
2. change app version and particular service version.
3. create package and remove Pkg folder from it for the service without modifications.
4. connect to Service Fabric and test like `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackagePath "..path" -ImageStoreConnectionString "fabric:ImageStore"`

Maybe somebody was able to overcome this issue? or at least has similar behavior so I'm not alone in Universe.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/259 
This is a bug in our code. It happens when a compressed package was uploaded and provisioned in the cluster. Testing a new version of the application fails because settings file was not found in the provisioned version.
We fixed the issue and it will become available in one of our next releases.
Meanwhile, you can skip compression or test the version 2 application package without passing in the image store connection string.
Apologies for the inconvenience!